# Why do we return dp[nums.length - 1] instead of dp[nums.length]? Don't we need the whole array?

Tags: javascript

> You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security systems connected and it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.
>
> Given an integer array `nums` representing the amount of money of each house, return the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.

Solution:

```
var rob = function(nums) {
    if (nums === null || nums.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    let dp = new Array(nums.length);
    dp[0] = nums[0];
    dp[1] = Math.max(nums[0], nums[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) {
        dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i-2] + nums[i], dp[i-1]);
    }
    return dp[nums.length - 1];
};
```

Base case:

- There's only 1 house: `dp[0] = nums[0];`
- There's only 2 houses: `dp[1] = Math.max(nums[0], nums[1]);`

More houses:

```
let dp = new Array(nums.length);
for (let i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) {
    dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i-2] + nums[i], dp[i-1]);
}
```

Max of current index + current index - 2 ?

So why are we subtracting 1 at return dp[nums.length-1]?

Comment: Array indexes are zero-based, but `.length` is 1-based. Ie, if you have an array of length 1, then that element is found at index 0. So the -1 converts between those two, and thus `dp[nums.length - 1]` gives you the last element of the array. `dp[nums.length]` would be *beyond* the end of the array.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate... yes it's [tag:java] and not [tag:javascript] but the answer still applies as it's a fundamental of all zero-based indexes